# Save/load Huggingface model and image processor from local disk

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to save the `microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition` Huggingface model (and potentially its image processor) to my local disk in Python 3.10. The goal is to load the model inside a Docker container later on without having to pull the model weights and configs from HuggingFace each time the container and Python server boots up.

#### Goal

```py
from transformers import pipeline

# instead of this
pipe = pipeline(
        task="object-detection",
        model="microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition",
)

# i'd like this 
pipe = pipeline(
        task="object-detection",
        model="./local_model_directory",
)
```

#### Saving/Loading Model with Pipe ❌ (Failed)

I tried to save the model with `pipe.save_pretrained("./local_model_directory")` and then load the model in the second run with `pipe("object-detection", model="./local_model_directory"). This throws an error and doesn't work at all.

##### 1. Run: Saving to Local Disk ✅

```py
pipe = pipeline(
        task="object-detection",
        model="microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition",
)

pipe.save_pretrained("./local_model_directory")
```

The following files are saved to `./local_model_directory`:

- `config.json`
- `pytorch_model.bin`

##### 2. Run: Loading from Local Disk ❌ (Fails)

```py
pipe = pipeline(
        task="object-detection",
        model="./local_model_directory",
)
```

Error:
`OSError: ./local_model_directory does not appear to have a file named preprocessor_config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/./local_model_directory/None' for available files.`

#### Manually Downloading Weights and Config ❌ (Fails)

I manually downloaded the missing [`preprocessor_config.json`](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition/resolve/main/preprocessor_config.json) and `model.safetensors` from Huggingface and added them to `./local_model_directory`.

Running the pipe as before generates a new error.

```py
pipe = pipeline(
        task="object-detection",
        model="./local_model_directory",
)
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

#### Saving/Loading Model with `model.save...`  (Works with Warnings)

Then I tried loading and saving the model and its image processor manually without `pipeline` like so:

##### 1. Attempt - Works with Warnings

```py
from transformers import AutoFeatureExtractor, AutoModelForObjectDetection

extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition"
)
model = AutoModelForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(
    "microsoft/table-transformer-structure-recognition"
)

extractor.save_pretrained("./local_model_directory")
model.save_pretrained("./local_model_directory")
```

Three files are saved to `./local_model_directory`:

- `config.json`
- `preprocessor_config.json`
- `pytorch_model.bin`

Loading the model with `pipeline("object-detection", model="./local_model_directory")` works this time, but I get a warning:

`python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/detr/feature_extraction_detr.py:28: FutureWarning: The class DetrFeatureExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in version 5 of Transformers. Please use DetrImageProcessor instead.`

Comment: you could try using git lfs to download the model and then copy the model into your docker image. This works for me using the Donut transformer